# Gauge values in Chronosphere Pushgateway only last for a couple of minutes

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a hourly batch jobs in which I defined a gauge metrics where I'd `set_to_current_time` at certain time in the program.

However when I see it in chronosphere, it will show with gaps in the graph instead of a continuous curve.

[image: chronosphere graph]

The intent is to generate alerts once the gauge value become too old. In order to make this alert, I intend to use `(time() - series) / 3600 > 1.5` as a criteria. However this won't work if series are bunch of empty values.

So the question is, is there a way to interpolate the curve to use the last non-empty value? Or is there a different way of doing it?

Previously, we were using open source prometheus pushgateway and it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`last_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) for your values. For example to fill the gaps in graph from screenshot you could use

```
last_over_time(series[3h])
```

It'll fill the gaps with latest value of `series` over last three hours.

Regarding your alert rule: its `expr:` would look something like

```
(time() - last_over_time(series[3h])) / 3600 > 1.5
```